# CDO - Difference between "daymean" and "ydaymean" operators?

Tags: netcdf, cdo-climate, era5

I want to calculate daily mean of hourly temperature data from ERA5 data for 1975-2005. I have merged the downloaded hourly NETCDF files to create a single NETCDF file containing temperature and total precipitation data for all years. I think "daymean" operator would be suitable for this task but then I see another operator which is "ydaymean" for multi-year data in cdo. How are they both different and do they give different results? In which case using one can be beneficial over the other?

```
cdo -daymean -selvar,2 metre temperature infile outfile
```

or

```
cdo -ydaymean -selvar,2 metre temperature infile outfile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

daymean is the simply the daily mean, whereas ydaymean gives you the daily mean over all years (the average of all Jan1, the average of all Jan2 etc) - just look at the dates in the output file and don't forget to check the online documentation, it is very well written.